# rotate an animated image in gnuplot with the mouse

Tags: javascript, 3d, rotation, gnuplot, gif

I created some 3D animated gifs using *gnuplot*. I am having trouble seeing all of the splotted data in the gifs.

Using the 'set view' command is not optimal as the splotting is automated and the data varies from plot to plot, so where one view might work for one set of data, it would not work for another set of data.

I think it would be good to let the user rotate the axis with his/her mouse in order to see different angles. I know this is possible in for instance the x11 terminal, but can it be done with a gif? Perhaps it is possible using the canvas terminal and *JavaScript*.

Another option might be to rotate the image around an axis automatically, so that when it loads it is already rotating, and continues to rotate as the data is animated.

Is there a way to do this in gnuplot?

Comment: No, there is no 3D-interactive output format.

Comment: Would it help to plot one dataset to the X11 terminal, use `pause -1` to wait until you adjusted the view point with your mouse, and after create the animation? It's not interactive nor fully automated, but the simplest/ fastest way to do it by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second option is possible. You can set the viewing angle in each iteration.

```
set terminal gif animate delay 5 loop 0 optimize
set output "rot.gif"

unset surface
set pm3d at s

set label "sin(x)" at screen 0.7, 0.9

n = 100
do for [i=1:n] {
   set view 60, i*360/n
   splot sin(x) notitle
}

set output
```

Notes:

- The key moves from iteration to iteration, so I have replaced it by a fixed label.
- `i*360/n` creates one complete rotation of the plot within one complete animation

[image: rotating animated gif]